# Error while querying SAP HANA from SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, hana

The query below is working fine when the where clause specifies the column `ORDER_UPDATED`:

> `SELECT *  FROM OPENQUERY(DS_64, 'SELECT  TOP 1         *            FROM "workforce"."sales" WHERE ORDER_UPDATED > ''2020-07-24 14:03:23''            ')`

When I'm using `ORDER_CREATED` instead:

> `SELECT *  FROM OPENQUERY(DS_64, 'SELECT  TOP 1         *            FROM "workforce"."sales" WHERE ORDER_CREATED > ''2020-07-24 14:03:23''            ')`

I'm getting the below error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DS_64" returned message
> "[SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;314 numeric overflow:
> search table error:  [6944] exception 70006944: AttributeEngine:
> overflow in numeric calculation

Any help is going to be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this table have any computed columns?

Comment: I do not think so. When I'm using ORDER_UPDATED in the where condition, the query is working fine. It is giving the error when I'm using ORDER_CREATED in the where condition

Comment: Also, you are using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` and the query may return random results.

Comment: I'm using TOP 1 just to check that I'm getting any result or not. If I remove TOP 1 then also, I'm getting the same error

Comment: Does this statement `SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(DS_64, 'SELECT ORDER_CREATED FROM "workforce"."sales" WHERE ORDER_CREATED > ''2020-07-24 14:03:23'' '`) return an error (this is a check for possible computed column)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it returns an error

Comment: I don't think it likes your datetime constant. Have you tried something like `TO_SECONDDATE(''2020-07-24 14:03:23'', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'')`? Ref: [TO_SECONDDATE()](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20f057b075191014809a8f010c03d7c2.html)

Comment: The error is reported on HANA side. Is `WORKFORCE.SALES` a view by any chance? If so, please check whether it contains an aggregated column e.g. `SUM` and a data type definition that may turn out too small for the aggregated result (e.g. `INT` for large counts etc.)

Comment: Yes, Worforce.Sales is a view

Comment: @AritraSarkar (rephrasing Lars Br. comment into question) Which aggregated columns e.g. `SUM` are defined in `WORKFORCE.SALES` and which data type definitions are these columns? Does your query run without failing if you reduce the number of selected lines e.g. `WHERE ORDER_CREATED between '2020-07-24 14:03:23' and '2020-07-24 14:03:23'` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax for top is limited in the HANA universe.  Also, check the datatype HANA is actually using from HANA Studio.